# Location services warning, even when they're enabled

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

```
if (kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@" Please go to settings  and enable them if you want to use all the features of this app  " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [servicesDisabledAlert show];
}
```

The alert pops up even if the location services are enabled.

This code is placed in the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking that a constant is not nil, which will always be true

You need to check the current authorisation status:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
```

edit: RazorSharp makes a good point. Also things which are camel cased but begin with a lower case k will generally be constants

Comment: Also note that `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` is not the only reason location services may not be available. It is better to check if location services aren't allowed: `!= kCLAuthorizationStatusAllowed`